# right way to define jquery attr variables?

Tags: jquery, variables, attr

can somebody explain why is this code doesnt work

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
 $('a').each(function() {
    var linkhref = $('a').attr('href');   
    if (linkhref == '/second2.php'){   
    $(this).css('color','red');   
    }   
    });   
    });
```

and if i change third line to

```
 var linkhref = $(this).attr('href');
```

it runs. Aren't these two var strings equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the loop, you need to maintain the reference to the current element of the array under iteration, as you wish to update each element of the array.

When you use `$('a').attr('href');`, that line will invoke **another** search (at the time of execution) for `a` elements in the page and return you the `href` attribute of the first anchor element found on the page. Thereby, you are losing the reference to the array variable under iteration.

For the same reason, the usage `$(this).css('color', 'red');` is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the selector

```
var $a = $('a');
```

`$a` will be an array of all the `a` DOM elements.

You could do:

```
var $a = $('a');
$.each($a, function(indexOfArray, element) {
  if (element.href == '/second2.php') {
    $(element).css('color','red');
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').each(function() {
   var $a = $(this);
   if ($a.attr('href') == '/second2.php') {
     $a.css('color', 'red');
   }
 });
});
```

You want to minimise the times you use a selector, so assign to `$a`.